# Split the Linux terminal into to two

Tags: linux, terminal-emulator

I just want a terminal based package that could be installed with `sudo apt-get install packagename` that should split my terminal into two sessions. I'm using WSL2 in Windows 11. Any help will be appreciated...

Image ref: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

byobu (based on tmux) can do this.

```
sudo apt-get install byobu
byobu
<Press CTRL+F2>
```

You can even create more splits.

There is zero mouse support:

- To switch between the previous and the next, press SHIFT-F3, or SHIFT-F4 the other way round.
- To scroll up and down there are similarly non-intuitive shortcuts: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu

[image]

Comment: Byobu is nice wrapper. As backend, it uses tmux or screen.